# A Good Phrase to Replace "Get To Know"

Tags: word-choice, expressions, phrase-requests

This is what I want to express:

> I want to *get to know* more algorithms that have been created.

I have thought about changing the sentence into

> I want to *gain a better insight into* algorithms that have been created.

But it seems inappropriate.

Any better phrase (or single word) to replace *get to know*?

(Or better way to construct the sentence?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Any better phrase (or single word) to replace get to know?

My first thought was *learn* and my second was *discover*.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, *get to know* and *gain a better insight into* are not quite the same.

Your choice of the right phrase depends on the depth/ extent to which you want to know.

***Know*** would be the simplest option:

> I want to know more algorithms ...
>   (Are there any more than what I now know? If so, what are their names? - You now do not know of more; don't know if any exist.)

***learn***, ***explore***, ***study***, ***master***, ... would be good alternatives of various degrees.

Answer (score 1):

If you were talking about people, not algorithms, I'd recommend "*become familiar with*."

However, for algorithms, I'd be more inclined to use:

> *better understand the algorithms*

or,

> *more fully comprehend the algorithms*

I'm sure there are other viable alternatives, too.

My dictionary defines comprehend as *grasp mentally; understand*, so it seems like an especially apt word.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

> I want to become more familiar with more algorithms that have been created.

I am not sure of you're meanings but it sounds like you want to increase the *number* of algorithms you know, so maybe this might work:

> I want to be aware of more algorithms that have been created.

Answer (score 0):

Some options are:

1. *to familiarize oneself* [better];
2. *to acquaint oneself* [better]; or
3. *to master* (a subject matter or process).

I would use *better* rather than *more*, if you must use an adverb, because more, as a previous commenter mentioned, could be thought to modify the *number of algorithms* rather than your familiarity with them.

Answer (score 0):

I would've said *learn about*.

Answer (score 0):

To express understanding something in its fullness, I've always liked the word *[grok](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/grok)*:

> **grok**, *v*. : to understand profoundly and intuitively

So: *I want to grok all of the applicable algorithms.*

Answer (score 0):

A few options:

> I want to *gain a deeper understanding of* more algorithms that have been created.
>
> ---
>
> I want to *better understand the intricacies of* <strike>more</strike> *existing*/*modern* algorithms <strike>that have been created</strike>.
>
> ---
>
> I want to *expand my knowledge of existing* algorithms.
>
> ---
>
> I want to *further develop my knowledge/understanding of existing* algorithms.