# Another phrase for ‘get to know someone’

Tags: phrases, synonyms

I want to write something like

> I got to know him when ...

I thought of discovered and learned but they don’t feel right

> I discovered him when ...

Discovered sounds like I’ve become a scientist that found a new species and

> I learned about him by ...

Learned just sounds wrong.

Any suggestions for replacing “get to know”?

Comment: Why don't you want to use "get/got to know"? Are you just over using it in a particular text or does it lack some meaning that you also want to convey?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A Good Phrase to Replace "Get To Know"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/63991/a-good-phrase-to-replace-get-to-know) Though the object referent in the example sentence there is a topic rather than a person, some suggestions work in both cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I became acquainted with him when...

[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/acquainted#:%7E:text=If%20you%20get%20or%20become,people%20get%20or%20become%20acquainted.) says:

> If you ***get*** or ***become acquainted*** with someone that you do not know, you talk to each other or do something together so that ***you get to know each other***. You can also say that two people get or become acquainted.

[WordHippo](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/become_acquainted_with.html) gives you some synonyms, so you could also say:

> I ***made his acquaintance*** or I ***met him*** when...

Answer (score 0):

Synonyms for get to know:
meet; become acquainted with; become acquainted; make the acquaintance of; realize; contain; grasp; hold.

Comment: What's the source of these synonyms?